# Window Open in IE not working

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me understand why this link works perfectly in firefox but in IE the pop up window doesn't work?

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open('/assets/flash/sage200demo.html', 'Sage 200 Demo', 'width=1024,height=768,status=0,resizable=0')">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spaces in the 2nd argument to `window.open` are causing the problem.  This argument is the window name and IE doesn't like it if you have spaces in it.  This will work:

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open('/assets/flash/sage200demo.html', 'Sage200Demo', 'width=1024,height=768,status=0,resizable=0');">
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4sQ/**

Comment: Note: a [user comment on the MSDN docs for `window.open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx#11) confirms this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change it to the following:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('/assets/flash/sage200demo.html', 'Sage200Demo', 'width=1024,height=768,status=0,resizable=0');return false;">
```

or better yet

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('/assets/flash/sage200demo.html', 'Sage200Demo', 'width=1024,height=768,status=0,resizable=0');return false;">
```

or better yet

```
<script>
function openWindow(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('/assets/flash/sage200demo.html', 'Sage200Demo', 'width=1024,height=768,status=0,resizable=0');
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openWindow(event);">
```